# ftplib - 550 Home directory does not exist but Filezilla is working

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftplib

I have a problem logging into a sftp (ssh) server with this code:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import ftplib

ftp_host = 'XXX'
ftp_user = 'XXX'
ftp_pass = 'XXX'

ftps = FTP_TLS(ftp_host)
ftps.login(ftp_user, ftp_pass)
ftps.prot_p()

filenames = ftps.nlst()
print(filenames)
ftps.quit()
```

It results in error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download2.py", line 9, in <module>
    ftps.login(ftp_user, ftp_pass)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 733, in login
    return FTP.login(self, user, passwd, acct)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 403, in login
    resp = self.sendcmd('PASS ' + passwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 275, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 248, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Home directory does not exist
```

I can login with Filezilla and other sftp-clients without any problem. The server is out of my control so I cannot check server side logs.

Any idea?

Comment: Which credentials are you using to log in using Filezilla?

Comment: The same credentials used in the script. If I test incorrect credentials in the script, the error changes to "530 Login or password incorrect" - as expected.